# How to keep some data user input into some forms and save these into local device by using AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

Now I am trying to save some data user input into some forms and keep these in user's local device.
But, I have an error. ( Below pic)

[image]

I don't know why and how to solve this problem...
Followings are my code.
This is "state".

```
class PersonalInfo1 extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   userInput: [
     { fullname: '' },
     { middleName: '' },
     { reason: '' },
     { birthPlaceCity: '' },
     { birthPlaceCountry: '' },
     { Citizinchip: '' },
     { aboutMaridge: '' },
     { fromTermOfMaridge: '' },
     { ToTermOfMaridge: '' },
     { nameOfSpouse:'' },
     { birthdateOfSpouse: '' },
     { fromTermOfExMaridge: '' },
     { ToTermOfExMaridge: '' },
     { nameOfExSpouse: '' },
     { birthdateOfExSpouse: '' },
    ],
   };
 }
```

This is rest of code.

```
 componentDidMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('userInput')
   .then((userInput) => this.setState({ userInput }));
}

 onChangeText(text, name) {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('userInput')
    .then((userInput) => {
    if (userInput !== null) {
      this.state.userInput[name] = text;
      AsyncStorage.setItem('userInput', userInput);
    }
  });
}


  const { userInput } = this.state;
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <InfoHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}>
     申請者情報１ 
    </InfoHeader>
    <Notes />
    <QuestionTextSet
      onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'fullname')}
      placeholder={'例：留学太郎'}
      value={userInput.fullname}
      editable
    >
      姓名（漢字表記）
    </QuestionTextSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.userInput` is indexed array (0, 1, 2 ... ) with objects (e.g. { fullname: '' }) as a value. So, you can't access it in the following way:

```
this.state.userInput[name] = text;
```

Try to change `this.state` to the following one:

```
this.state = {
    userInput:
        {
            fullname: '',
            middleName: '',
            reason: '',
            birthPlaceCity: '',
            birthPlaceCountry: '',
            Citizinchip: '',
            aboutMaridge: '',
            fromTermOfMaridge: '',
            ToTermOfMaridge: '',
            nameOfSpouse: '',
            birthdateOfSpouse: '',
            fromTermOfExMaridge: '',
            ToTermOfExMaridge: '',
            nameOfExSpouse: '',
            birthdateOfExSpouse: ''
        }
};
```

... if it's acceptable in your case.

Comment: Thank you for helping.
I did that you mentioned but I cannot. Its problem is the same one....

Comment: Can you detect the line of the code where the error is?

Comment: Maybe here is.

componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userInput')
      .then((userInput) =>
      
      this.setState({ userInput }));
  }

Comment: componentWillMount or componentDidMount?

Comment: you have to be more sure with the line of the code where error occurs. try to comment it out to check if error will gone or add console.log(userInput) to debug what is provided into this.setState

Comment: componentDidMount is.
Because I tried to delete this line including componentDidMount and then this erro was gone.